# Facebook invalid hash key the second time I log in

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying to implement facebook login in my app, I followed the instructions provided by Facebook website and everything is working correctly, I can login. receive toke, get user info I need , everything works fine.

the second time I try to login it says ("logged in as : Name"), do you want to logout? , and weather I log out programmatically or I confirm this message and click yes, the next time I login it takes me to the login page showing this error:

invalid key hash, The key hash ******************** doesn't match any stored key hashes

the strange thing is when I go to my Facebook account and delete the app I can log in again normally!

I have no Idea what the cause might be so I don't know which piece of code I should put, any ideas?

Comment: copy the key hash that you're getting in developer.facebook.com for your app and paste there.

Comment: Why does work the first time?

Comment: I also had same problem and was getting this weird behaviour.

Comment: I am having this same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as Tauqir suggested, copying the hash key from facebook solved it
I have no Idea why is it working the first time and not the second though

I guess facebook sdk already changed at this point but worth keeping this here

Comment: It is working in my case also, But I dont know why it is generating a new key hash for the second time